# I have a string which I want to encrypt/decrypt using php but the output of the encryption should be lower case alphanumeric only

Tags: php, security

I have a string which I want to encrypt/decrypt using php but the output of the conversion after encryption should only be lowercase letters and numbers. Eg: "ae3ab9f41a8c737b1f81c0b5". and later I should be able to decrypt it

Comment: What have you tried, what isn't working? Post some code and come back here.

Comment: https://ignite.io/code/51399aa4ec221e9434000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

PHP Base32 Decoder: http://php-classes.de/class/base32/

this would generate only lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt as you see fit. Encode with Base32.

Decrypt by converting the Base32 stream back into the original encoding, then running the resultant string through your decryption method of choice.

Edit:
Why was I down voted? Is it because I didn't feed him code on a silver platter?